# Cant link files in directories

Tags: html, css

I have a folder named views inside that folder i have 2 files. landing.ejs and wow.css but can't link them

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wow.css">
```

Comment: @Chirag they don't seem to be asking where to *put* the link (although that might be why it's not linking)...

Comment: if your html page is in same dir as `wow.css` file, it must work, check your directory tree properly or give file pathes of your html and css file

Answer (score 0):

try it..you have to mention that path..
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="views/wow.css">`

Answer (score 0):

you should also include on the path whatever your folder name is so that the file inside it will be read

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfoldername/wow.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the thing you need to understand is that the path needs to be relativ from where your html file is.

E.g. you have this structure

```
website
   - index.html
   - views
       - wow.css
```

and you want to reference the wow.css in the index.html you need the path from the index.html to the wow.css -> **views/wow.css**

another example:

```
website
  - html
      - index.html
  - view
     - wow.css
```

your path would be **../views/wow.css**
Always relative to the file you want to link your css to.